# GlusterFS peer rejected and no data replication following reboot

Tags: linux, reboot, replication, glusterfs

I'm experimenting with glusterfs on ubuntu16.04.

Setup consists of:

- Gluster-server node1: ubuntu16-2
- Gluster-server node2: ubuntu16-3
- Gluster-client: ubuntu16-1

I've setup a gluster volume named 'gvol0' with 2 replicas across ubuntu16-2 and ubuntu16-3.

I've mounted gvol0 on ubuntu16-1 and created 2 files from this node and confirmed that a copy of the created files was created on both ubuntu16-2 and ubuntu16-3.

In order to test replication I switched off ubuntu16-3 and created 2 additional files on ubuntu16-1 and I could see the newly created files on ubuntu16-2 (since it was still powered on). I then powered up ubuntu16-3, and expected it to retrieve the changes made to the gvol0 volume in its absence, however it didn't.

What do I need to do to have ubuntu16-3 fetch the changes applied to gvol0 whilst it was powered off ?

Additionally, after powering up ubuntu16-3, when executing 'gluster peer status', from both ubuntu16-2 and ubuntu16-3, both peers where in 'Peer Rejected (Connected)' state. How can this be fixed without manually re-probing both peers?